# less.js 1.2.1 with other css styles, css styles not working

Tags: css, less

I have trouble with less.js. Less.js itselfs works fine, but when i want to link other css styles, it seems to loaded them, but it doesnt works. There is problem witch cache probably.

there is generated code:

```
 <link href="http://localhost/less/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less">
<link href="http://localhost/css/admin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/css">
<script src="http://localhost/js/less-1.2.2.js" type="text/javascript">
<style id="less:xxx:cz-web-static-less-bootstrap" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="http://localhost/js/head.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

So what is in bootstrap.less it works, but what is in admin.css doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

strictly speaking, rel="stylesheet/css", isn't valid. But it's possible there are more problems. We'd need to see some examples of the code. If you are utilizing LESS's nested selectors - each nesting level will potentially override your css elements even if you are calling it after your less file.

More simple put:

```
#mybody #mydiv p a
{
  style
}
```

which is potentially a very easy string to create with nested LESS structure - WILL override a

```
a
{
  style
}
```

in your CSS.